# check How many Time Document is view from SharePoint Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, web-part

In custom web part how to check how many Time Document is view from SharePoint Document Library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [enable auditing](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) for tracking and reporting on Document views. It's possible using the Audit Logging feature in SP:

- Configuring Audit Logging: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA102866204.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102772739
- View Audit Log Reports: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102772739.aspx
- Find the most visited sites in SharePoint: https://www.lepide.com/how-to/track-most-visited-sites-in-sharepoint-2013.html